# how to display django search results in template

Tags: django

I am new to django and I am working on a project. I need to create a search functionality where users can search data in models, I've tried coding in this way but even when I searched for items that are in models, It doesn't displayed any result.

view.py

```
def search(request):
query = request.GET.get('q')
results = Myhouses.objects.filter(Q(name_of_accomodation__icontains=query) | Q(type_of_room__icontains=query) | Q(location__icontains=query))

return render(request, 'account/index.html')
```

template

```
<form method='GET' action='{% url "search" %}'>
    <input type='text' name='q' placeholder="Enter Search Keyword" value='{{ request.GET.q }}' id='intry'>
    <input type='submit' value='Search' class='button_1' id='sub1'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the [Django tutorial (Part 3)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial03/)

for example:

views

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')
    results = Myhouses.objects.filter(Q(name_of_accomodation__icontains=query) | Q(type_of_room__icontains=query) | Q(location__icontains=query))

    return render(request, 'account/index.html', {'results': results})
```

template

```
<ul>
{% for element in results %}
    <li>{{ element }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```